# ASP.NET MVC binding DropDownList and Checkbox to ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a huge job offer post form, and I wanted to increase priority of properties by clicking checkbox next to them.

For example:

Salary         X

TeamSize       O

SomeTechnology X

Where X is checked and O isn't.

I've came across a problem where I need to have a drop down list and checkbox next to it, and then bind it to the viewModel. I couldn't make the last step working though.

HomeController

```
public ActionResult CandidateRegister()
{
    CandidateRegisterViewModel viewModel = new CandidateRegisterViewModel();

    viewModel.SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel = new SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel()
    {
        EmploymentType =
            new SelectList(
                Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enums.EmploymentType)).Cast<Enums.EmploymentType>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = v.ToString(),
                    Value = ((int)v).ToString()
                }).ToList(), "Value", "Text"),
        Selected = false
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

ViewModels

```
 public class CandidateRegisterViewModel
 {  
       public SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel { get; set; }
 }          

 public class SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel
 {
      public SelectList EmploymentType { get; set; }
      public bool Selected { get; set; }
      public int? SelectedEmployment { get; set; }
 }
```

EmploymentType enum

```
 public enum EmploymentType
 {
      [Display(Name = "Full Time")]
      FullTime,
      [Display(Name = "Part Time")]
      PartTime,
      Contract,
      Internship,
      Other
 }
```

CandidateRegister View

```
@model SourceTreeITMatchmaking.Models.CandidateRegisterViewModel    

<div class="white-container sign-up-form">
@using (Html.BeginForm("CandidateRegister", "Candidates"))
{ 
    <section>
         <h6 class="bottom-line">Essentials:</h6>

         <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                   <div class="col-sm-7" style="padding-left: 0;">

                        @Html.DropDownList("SelectedEmployment", Model.SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel.EmploymentType)
                        @Html.CheckBox("Selected", Model.SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel.Selected)

                   </div>
               </div>
          </div>
    </section>
</div>

     <hr class="mt60">
     <div class="clearfix">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-large pull-right" value="Register candidate!">
     </div>
}
```

This is what I tried so far.
Yet again, what I want to achieve is that I have a drop down list of my EmploymentType enum, checkbox next to it and then bind it to SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel so I could put it in CandidateRegisterViewModel (which has a number of other properties, like Address etc.)

I hope You could help me a little :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the strongly typed helpers so you bind to your model - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel.SelectedEmployment, Model.SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel.EmploymentType)` and `@Html.CheckBox(m => m.SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel.Selected)`

Comment: You should also look carefully at the assignment of `EmploymentType` - all you need is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` - to convert it to `List<>` is pointless extra overhead, and to then convert that to another `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` by using the `SelectList` constructor is even more so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you can not bind it to view model is that your input names are incorrect. Either change them to:

`@Html.DropDownList("SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel.SelectedEmployment", Model.SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel.EmploymentType)`

and

```
@Html.CheckBox("SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel.Selected", Model.SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel.Selected)
```

Or a much better solution would be using a strongly typed helpers:

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="col-sm-7" style="padding-left: 0;">
              @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel.SelectedEmployment , Model.SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel.EmploymentType)

              @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel.Selected)

          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Also if you have multiple nested models you can create editor templates for them:

```
@model SourceTreeITMatchmaking.Models.SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel

<section>
<h6 class="bottom-line">Essentials:</h6>
   <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="col-sm-7" style="padding-left: 0;">
                  @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedEmployment , Model.EmploymentType)    
                  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Selected)

              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Save it in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel.cshtml

And then in your main view you can use them like this:

```
@model SourceTreeITMatchmaking.Models.CandidateRegisterViewModel    

<div class="white-container sign-up-form">
@using (Html.BeginForm("CandidateRegister", "Candidates"))
{ 
      @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.SelectedEmploymentTypeViewModel)

     <hr class="mt60">
     <div class="clearfix">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-large pull-right" value="Register candidate!">
     </div>
}
```

This way you will be able to cleanup your main view and to encapsulate and reuse the editor templates wherever they needed.